# Событие клика на кнопку

Tags: php, sql

Как сделать событие клика на кнопку?

В C# нажал 2 раза, и событие сгенерировалось, а в php не знаю как. Прочитал одну книгу, вроде бы основы понял, но как сделать событие - нет.

К примеру, у меня есть кнопка Submit и есть запрос:

```
<?
    $res = mysql_querty("INSERT INTO t_links (URL) VALUES('http://hashcode.ru')");
?>
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Запрос должен находиться в php файле, а форма в другом файле.

```
<form method='post' action='/путь/к/пхп_файлу_с_запросом.php'>

//Здесь по желанию указывать дополнительные параметры для передачи данных

<input type='submit' value="Отправить" />

</form>
```

В отдельном пхп указываете свой запрос:

```
<?
$res = mysql_querty("INSERT INTO t_links (URL) VALUES('http://hashcode.ru')");
?>
```

Comment: Поправка: 

    mysql_query

Comment: А вот ещё вопрос, а если это будет к примеру форма входа?

Comment: То, где я написал "//Здесь по желанию указывать доп. параметры" нужно дописать другие инпуты (формы ввода).

<input type="text" name="login" />

<input type="password" name="password" />

А уже отосланные данные обрабатываете в php файле.